# Debugging Google Web Fonts

Tags: html, css, font-face

i am think i am using similar code i used b4 but seems like the fonts aren't loading

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:extralight,light,regular,bold"></script>
        <style>
        h1, h2, h3 { font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz"; color: red } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is some text</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script>` to embed a CSS style sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the font using a `<link>` tag.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:extralight,light,regular,bold">`

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Webfont page](http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz#code) the correct notation is:

```
<link href=' http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:extralight,light,regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered another issue that can cause the fonts to not load.  If you define a font as

```
family=Arapey:italic
```

then you need to use the css, like so

```
font-family: 'Arapey';
font-style:italic;
```

if you leave out

```
font-style:italic;
```

then the font will not load in Chrome (and possibly other browsers?).  Although it will work in Firefox without it.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the CSS file as a Script file by mistake.

```
<script src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:extralight,light,regular,bold"></script>
```

Should be

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also put this in your .css file

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Me+Again+Down+Here");

you won't end up cluttering up your HTML with all these silly link tags. google shows this under 'advanced'.

watch out if you're using LESSCSS because @ defines a variable. let me know if there's a way to escape that - I couldn't find one!